# Разница между датами в днях

Tags: c++, календарь

Вообщем, ввожу данные 1-й даты и 2-й даты и пытаюсь найти разницу между ними в днях, решил для начала найти разницу в днях в месяцах и годах, месяцы и годы перевожу в дни и все суммирую, но кол-во месяцев не подсчитывает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
int year_user, mon_user, day_user;
int current_year, current_mon, current_day;
int num_days, num_mon=0, num_years;
int leap_year = 0, leap_like = 0;
int m, m1, i, j;
int M[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
cout<<"Введите год месяц и день вашего дня рождения(в формате ГГГГ М Д):"<<endl;
   cin>>year_user>>mon_user>>day_user;
cout<<"Ваша дата рождения:"<<year_user<<"."<<mon_user<<"."<<day_user<<endl;
cout<<"Введите желаему дату для вычесления количество дней(в формате ГГГГ М Д):"<<endl; 
   cin>>current_year>>current_mon>>current_day;
cout<<"Желаемая дата:"<<current_year<<"."<<current_mon<<"."<<current_day<<endl;
//рассчитываем количество лишних дней
   num_days = day_user - current_day;
   num_days = abs(num_days);
cout<<"Количество дней между датами:"<<num_days<<endl;
//проверяем какой из месяцев больше для корректной работы(ПРОБЛЕМА) 

 if (mon_user >= current_mon)
{
    int m = mon_user;
    int m1 = current_mon; 
}
else
{
    int m = current_mon; 
    int m1 = mon_user;
}

//рассчитываем количество лишних месяцев    
for(i=m; i<m1; i++)
{
 num_mon += M[i-1];
}

cout<<"Количество дней между месяцами:"<<num_mon<<endl;

//рассчитываем количество лет между датами и проверяем высокосный ли он

for(j=year_user; j<current_year; j++)
{
    if((j%4 == 0 && j%100 != 0) || (j%400 == 0))
    {
        num_years += 366;   

    }
    else
    {
        num_years += 365;
    }
}
  cout<<"Количество дней между годами:"<<num_years<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218894/number-of-days-between-two-dates-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы не мучил эти дни, месяцы и годы... Есть такое хорошее понятие как [юлианская дата](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) с хорошо разработанным алгоритмом расчета, и ваша задача - просто вычисление разности двух таких дат.

Если вы не планируете работать с датами до введения григорианского календаря и учитывать введение в России григорианского в 1918 году :), то вам достаточно запрограммировать это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, даже ни одного условного перехода :)

Comment: действительно, вышло намного проще и удобней, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти возраст в днях, можно готовую библиотеку использовать, к примеру, [date.h для C++11/c++14](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h" 

int main()
{
  using namespace date;
  sys_days birthday;
  if(!(std::cin >> parse("%Y %m %d", birthday)))
    return 1; // error
  sys_days today = floor<days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
  std::cout << (today - birthday).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14  -I/path/to/date *.cc
$ echo 1982 6 25 | ./a.out
12864
```

Вот [пример, который принимает во внимание время дня](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#2gs-birthday).

Comment: чем минус вызван?

Comment: спасибо, приму во внимание! По минусу не ко мне