# Как посчитать разницу двух дат на питоне?

Tags: python

Конечно легко это сделать, импортируя календарь используя тайм сплит и др.
А как это сделать без всяких импортировок и вводов?
То есть:

> Формат входных данных
>
> Даны два дня в формате: день, месяц и год. Года в обеих датах не превышают 105 и гарантируется, что первый день строго раньше второго дня.
>
> Формат результата
>
> Выведите количество прошедших лет.
>
> Например:
> ввод
> 1 9 2011
> 10 9 2012
>
> вывод
> 1

и др?

Comment: [Разница между датами в днях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/717266/519463)

Comment: Что-то здесь не так. Вы, по-видимому, не знаете почти ничего из Питона, но интересует вас именно такая конкретная задача.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разница между датами в днях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717207/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выведите количество прошедших лет.

если вопрос стоит именно так, то задача упрощается - просто вычитаем из одного года другой, ну и уменьшаем на единицу если год не полный:

```
d1,m1,y1 = map(int,input().split())
d2,m2,y2 = map(int,input().split())

res = y2-y1-(m1>m2 or m1==m2 and d1>d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Отличный вариант вам предложил [Алексей Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0), если не брать в расчет никакие библиотеки. И оно вам максимально подходит, т.к. количество лет у вас всего до 105, а в те времена и вплоть до 17 века использовался юлианский календарь.

Ваш Ввод дат:

```
x = input()
y = input()
```

Сделаем разбивку и инты из каждого, а также назначим день, месяц и год для каждого:

```
first = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
second = [int(i) for i in y.split()]
day_1, month_1, year_1 = first[0], first[1], first[2]
day_2, month_2, year_2 = second[0], second[1], second[2]
```

функция для вычисления количества дней, как из ссылки комментария:

```
def jul(day, month, year):
    a = (14 - month)//12
    y = year + 4800 - a
    m = month + 12 * a - 3
    if year % 4 == 0:
        day += 1
    jdn = day + (153 * m + 2)//5 + 365 * y + y//4 - y//100 + y//400 - 32045
    return jdn
```

Вычисляем количество дней, а потом и лет. (берем инт, чтобы было округление до меньшего, т.к. нам нужно количество полных лет)

```
count_of_days_1 = jul(day_1, month_1, year_1)
count_of_days_2 = jul(day_2, month_2, year_2)
count_of_years = int((count_of_days_2 - count_of_days_1)/365)

>>> count_of_years
```

p.s. разные исключения, которые возможны или их обработка - напишите сами.

Comment: Вместо `day_1, month_1, year_1 = first[0], first[1], first[2]` может выть просто `day_1, month_1, year_1 = first`.

Comment: `int` в последней команде излишний.

Comment: @MarianD почему он лишний?)

Comment: Вы прав, он не лишний, моя ошибка, извините меня.

Comment: Однако он лишний. Я не закончил мой комментарий: «`int` в последней команде излишний, *когда вместо обычного деления (`/`) примените целочисленное (`//`).*»

Comment: :D , однако, если не использовать целочисленное деление - он не лишний)